# React: how to compare current props.children with new one

Tags: javascript, compare, reactjs

Hi,

i am building component which acts only as wrapper for some other generated content and uses third party library. This library works with `props.children` of component. So far so good, but this thrird party library is little laggy when applied, or refreshed on element. And because only reason to refresh this library is when `props.children` changed I am trying to figure how to compare `this.props.children` and `nextProps.children` in `shouldComponentUpdate`. I was thinking that PureRenderMixin should do the work, but for me it does not works. Component is rerendered even if I change only `state.listName` as it is in example below.

```html
<div>
  List name '{this.state.listName}'
  <br />
  <MyComponent>
    <ul>
      {listOfLi}
    </ul>
  </MyComponent>
</div>
```

Is there any way, how to manage comparing of `props.children` or any other option how to do something like that?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of child `key` prop that React suggests that arrays of children should be given to uniquely identify them. Because each child has a key, you can reliably tell whether children has changed across prop changes (this is the entire point of keys!). If the keys don't match between new and old then they have changed.

```
React.render(<App><Child key='1'/><Child key='2'/></App>, document.body)
```

and do the check in the App component you want to check before each update if the children changed

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps){
   var oldKeys = this.props.children.map( child => child.key);
   var newKeys = nextProps.children.map( child => child.key);

   //compare new and old keys to make sure they are the same
}
```

Note that this doesn't tell you if the content of each child has changed, you have to compare each by some criteria (such as deeply comparing props) if you want to know if *nothing* in the whole tree below this point has changed

as an even further optimization we know that children will never change as result of a state change so we can actually do our comparing in `componentWillReceiveProps()` and just set some state property like `childrenHaveChanged`

Comment: Elegant solution, but does not fully works for me. I have to check inner components too. I tried to make function, which traverse all childrens and their childrens and generate some kind of footprint from (div, span ...), className and style. Properties which has effect on dom position, sizing etc. But i am still not satisfied. I guess i will have to do update manually

Comment: This also fails to work for a single root child element.

Comment: This answer inaccurate. The key prop is used by React to efficiently manage updates caused by manipulating a list of items, such as by insertions, deletions, and reorders. Comparing key values will tell you only if your collection is composed of the the same number of objects with those key values. The objects themselves could be completely different data.

Comment: with React16 you can wrap the `listOfLi` with a Fragment and put a key on that and then just compare Fragment keys

Answer (score 4):

As **Matt S** pointed out, the accepted answer is kind of a fragile workaround and would depend on a non-standard use of `key`. Aside from the list examples he listed, even using something like `key={id}` would fall down if your `id`s remained the same but certain fields were modified in the resources they represent.

This [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8669) contains a good discussion on the topic and ends with a more stable [workaround](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8669#issuecomment-531515508). Essentially, you can simplify the `children` prop in a way that allows you to run a *deep comparison*. You can use the `React.Children` utilities to write the simplification methods:

```js
// Flattens all child elements into a single list
const flatten = (children, flat = []) => {
    flat = [ ...flat, ...React.Children.toArray(children) ]

    if (children.props && children.props.children) {
        return flatten(children.props.children, flat)
    }

    return flat
}

// Strips all circular references and internal fields
const simplify = children => {
    const flat = flatten(children)

    return flat.map(
        ({
            key,
            ref,
            type,
            props: {
                children,
                ...props
            }
        }) => ({
            key, ref, type, props
        })
    )
}
```

Then you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` or `React.memo` to prevent re-renders:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ children }) => (
    <div>{ children }</div>
)

export default React.memo(MyComponent, (prev, next) => (
    JSON.stringify(simplify(prev.children)) ===
    JSON.stringify(simplify(next.children))
))
```

These utilities + `JSON.stringify` are just one approach, the one mentioned in [the comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8669#issuecomment-531515508) is similar and you could also leverage utilities like `lodash.isequal` for the deep comparison. Unfortunately I don't know of any one or two liners for this comparison but please comment if you know a simpler stable way to do this!

Answer (score 2):

Something about the design and behavior you describe is off. You should rarely, if ever, have to concern yourself with performing manual diffs of `children`. That should be left to React. If the library you are using is choking every time the component updates, regardless of whether it's because of `children` or some other state/prop change, it is not written reactively and you should look for a different one that is written reactively. Or you could contribute to fixing that behavior in the open source project, either by opening an issue or submitting a pull request.

It's not easy to do what you're trying to do because it shouldn't be necessary. React is very, very good at handling reconciliation and will only render when something has actually changed that will change the state of the DOM relevant to it.